# How to color index and column names cells in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, css, pandas, latex

on this page
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex.html

we can find description of `styler.to_latex()` funcion. How can I color not only the values in dataframe cells, but the index, columns and upper-left corner too like in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Use the `applymap_index` and `apply_index` methods to add CSS styles to the indexes (that are valid to be converted to Latex) or add direct Latex styles using the same methods. I do not believe the top left (blue area) is directly stylable in `to_latex`

Comment: That is the problem, I would like to color left blue area specifically

Comment: It is not natively possible. You have to do this youself with post-processing of the generated LaTeX.